# Elastic Beanstalk Change ELB Type

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-elb, amazon-waf

Does anyone know if it's possible to change an existing AWS Elastic Beanstalk environment to an Application Load Balancer (instead of a classic one).

As far as I know only Application ELB's can be protected with AWS WAF and DDOS "Shield" so any existing EB app can't take advantage of these features since they have classic ELB's.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Hello As Per AWS Documentation:

> The Elastic Beanstalk Environment Management Console only supports
>   creating and managing an Elastic Beanstalk environment with a Classic
>   Load Balancer. For other options, see [Application Load Balancer](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/environments-cfg-applicationloadbalancer.html) and
>   [Network Load Balancer.](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/environments-cfg-nlb.html)

Also

> Note You can only set the load balancer type during environment
>   creation. ([Refer AWS Documetnation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/environments-cfg-applicationloadbalancer.html))

So When you deploy application to Elastic Beanstalk via [AWS CLI](https://aws.amazon.com/cli/?sc_channel=PS&sc_campaign=acquisition_IN&sc_publisher=google&sc_medium=command_line_b&sc_content=aws_cli_e&sc_detail=aws%20cli&sc_category=command_line&sc_segment=159807028048&sc_matchtype=e&sc_country=IN&s_kwcid=AL!4422!3!159807028048!e!!g!!aws%20cli&ef_id=WYmLRAAABHhtuTxw:20171010123704:s):

Try

```
eb create test-env --elb-type network
```

or

`eb create test-env --elb-type application`

Comment: Thanks, that's a shame. It means any existing environments can't be changed I'd presume then.

Comment: As of now no according to official AWS documentation , do mark question solved if the answer clears your doubts

Comment: Annoying how coy the official docs are about this in [other places](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/userguide/migrate-to-application-load-balancer.html). You can use the EC2 load balancer migration wizard to generate a *second* application load balancer which forwards to the classic one, if you don't mind paying twice and it serves your purposes.

Comment: Seems like this answer is no longer true. It is possible to create the Application Load Balancer through the console. I did it myself too. https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2018/04/aws-elastic-beanstalk-console-supports-alb--/

Comment: indeed, one can now click the load balancer to configure it to any type, including shared application. It's still not possible to change it once configured though.

Comment: ELB docs for EB moved to https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/environments-cfg-alb.html

Answer (score 30):

It is not possible to change the load balancer type for an existing environment but I have used the following process to create a cloned environment with an application load balancer (instead of classic).

1. In the console, save configuration of the original env.
2. In terminal, `eb config get [save name]`, you will get a file in `.elasticbeanstalk\saved_configs` .
3. Edit the file to add

`OptionSettings:
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:environment:
    LoadBalancerType: application`

and remove (if you have those):

`aws:elb:loadbalancer:
    CrossZone: true
  aws:elb:policies:
    ConnectionDrainingEnabled: true
  aws:elb:listener:443:
    [whatever]`

You can use this opportunity to do other changes, such as upgrade `PlatformArn`

4. Save modified config as [new save name].
5. In terminal, `eb config put [new save name]` .
6. Update your `.ebextensions` to have `LoadBalancerType: application` and optionally add listener to elbv2. You can also create in the console manually later.

`aws:elbv2:listener:443:
    ListenerEnabled: true
    SSLPolicy: ELBSecurityPolicy-TLS-1-2-2017-01
    SSLCertificateArns: [your cert id]
    DefaultProcess: default
    Protocol: HTTPS
    Rules: ''`

7. Create a new env with `eb create [new env name] --cfg [new save name]`

Now you will have a new environment with a different load balancer type side-by-side with your old environment. You can perform testing, make further configuration changes and then if all is well, swap CNAMEs and terminate the previous environment.

Comment: This answer is nice, but it is not so easy to follow it to actually make the changes

Comment: This does not work anymore. editing , saving, uploading and loading the modified configuration now generates error 
"Unable to load configuration: Configuration validation exception: LoadBalancer type option cannot be changed."
[![when I  tried to do this ][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7PgTJ.png

Comment: @KapilAggarwal Are you creating a new environment with the new configuration or trying to apply the new configuration to the existing one? What happens if you use ``eb config put [new save name]`` as described and not the console for loading?

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way I've found to change an existing application to use the application load balancer is using both the Console and CLI:

1. In the console, save the application configuration of the original env. Note this name down. We'll use it as `<saved-config-name>`.
2. Under the **Application versions** note the latest **Version Label**. We'll use it as `<app-version>`.
3. From the CLI run `eb create <new-environment-name> --elb-type application --cfg <saved-config-name> --version <app-version>`
4. If you had HTTPs configured in the old application, in the newly created application reconfigure it in the Console under **Load Balancer**-->**Listeners** with the proper certificate.

Comment: It's worth noting that this in itself is not quite enough to update the complete EB environment - you will have to configure any load-balancer-related settings correctly, including eg listenes, SSL certs, security group configuration etc