# Elastic Beanstalk classic load balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-elb

Is there a way to migrate Elastic Beanstalks classic load balancer to application load balancer other than creating new environment?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46666169/elastic-beanstalk-change-elb-type/46666959#46666959

Answer (score 0):

Since [November 2017](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2017/11/new-one-step-migration-wizard-to-migrate-a-classic-load-balancer/), you can use the **Migration Wizard** to gradually migrate traffic from the Classic Load Balancer to the newly created Application Load Balancer. This does not require creating a new environment. Step-by-step guide available in the [AWS official docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/userguide/migrate-to-application-load-balancer.html).

Comment: So i followed the steps and created a new load balancer and created DNS entry too as guided, that's working fine. But when i deleted existing classic load balancer the environment health is marked as severe and cause is "Elastic Load Balancer (xxx) has been deleted." on the other hand i am able to access my instance via DNS entry that i made in route53 but if I paste a direct environment url in browser it is not accessible any help?

Comment: And if i go in elastic beanstalk environment config it's still showing "Load balancer type: classic"